# Thread.sleep() / robot.delay() more accurate?

Tags: java, sleep

I want to write a bot for a online game using the Robot class. My problem is now, that the method Thread.sleep() or robot.delay() is to inaccurate. Outside the game they work perfectly fine, with a deviation of approximately only 2 - 3 ms. But when the game is in focus, the methods have a deviation of +5 - +20 ms or even more. That is sadly enaugh to make my bot unusable. Is there any way to make these methods more accurate? Or are there any other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Beyond the passed sleeping-time the OS's scheduler decides when to start the thread. You can't influence that. You may want to not use `sleep` in that case and pause differently.

Comment: @akuzminykh thank you very much for your fast help, may I ask which diffrent methods/ways you would suggest to use?

Comment: @erikcox Hard to answer with this low amount of details and no code. ;-(

Comment: You cannot rely on timing in general.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no difference**

If you [browse the source](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.desktop/share/classes/java/awt/Robot.java#L663) for the JDK, `Robot.delay()` ends up calling `Thread.sleep()`.

```
public void delay(int ms) {
    checkDelayArgument(ms);
    Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
    if (!thread.isInterrupted()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (final InterruptedException ignored) {
            thread.interrupt(); // Preserve interrupt status
        }
    }
}
```

*You might be able to give the Java process a higher priority then the game, tasks might be executed more quickly after being given to the scheduler.*

Comment: Thank you Matt Clark, do you know by the way how I give my process a higher priority then the game?